# Kendo Javascript - loading instead of data rows

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a problem. here is my code:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        { YAxis: 1, LowLimit: 0, HighLimit: 100, Decimal: 2 }
    ],
    schema: {
        model: {
            fields: {
                YAxis: { type: "number", editable: false },
                LowLimit: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 0 } },
                HighLimit: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 0 } },
                Decimal: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 0 } }
            }
        }
    }
});

var kendoWidget = {
    dataSource: dataSource,
    columns: [
        { field: "YAxis", title: "Y-Axis", editable: false },
        { field: "LowLimit", title: "Low Limit" },
        { field: "HighLimit", title: "High Limit" },
        { field: "Decimal", title: "Decimal" }],
    editable: true
};
```

If I delete the data property the table works well and said to me "no data" but if I add the data property, console said kendo.all.min.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase'). What is the problem? I don't understand what's wrong in formatting, can someone who knows about kendo help me? Thank you.

Comment: What aren't you sharing with us? Your example works: https://dojo.telerik.com/idoBIjIf

Comment: is it possible that I have too old a version?

Comment: Which version of Kendo are you using?

Comment: Also, you have your data defined as numbers, but the JSON is represented as String.

Comment: I have 2018 version of kendo. I have updated the question with json number but still not working

Comment: 2018 works for me too: https://dojo.telerik.com/idoBIjIf/3

Comment: ok, thanks. maybe the problem is the format of data, thanks